# CLNDR.js not displaying correct in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

For a project of mine, I used the CLNDR.js plugin recently to create three small calendar views of the current and two upcoming months. However, because CLNDR.js natively does not support multiple event types (with different colors), I made a modification (including the css and underscore js template) to the code so it now does support multiple colors.

This works great in all browsers, except for IE where the first calendar (only one containing other event types at this time) keeps repeating the event for some strange reason:

[image: Calendar in IE10]

The template code (underscore.js) is:

```
<script id="calendar-template" type="text/template">
    <div class="days-container">
        <div class="days">
            <div class="headers">
                <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %>
                    <div class="day-header"><%= day %></div>
                <% }); %>
            </div>
            <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
                <% if(_.isEmpty(day.events)) { %>
                    <div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>">          <%= day.day %></div>
                <% }else{ %>
                    <% _.each(day.events, function(event) { %>
                        <div class="<%= day.classes %>
                            <%= event.type %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><%= day.day %>
                        </div>
                    <% }); %>
                <% } %>
            <% }); %>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The javascript function to initialize CLNDR.js into the containers using the template:

```
function initiateCalendar(events){
$("#cal_month_1").html("<h4 style='margin-left: 20px;'>" + moment().add(1, 'months').format("MMMM") + "</h4>");
$('#clndr_1').clndr({
    template: $('#calendar-template').html(),
    startWithMonth: moment(),
    showAdjacentMonths: true,
    events: events
});

$("#cal_month_2").html("<h4 style='margin-left: 20px;'>" + moment().add(2, 'months').format("MMMM") + "</h4>");
$('#clndr_2').clndr({
    template: $('#calendar-template').html(),
    startWithMonth: moment().add(1, 'months'),
    showAdjacentMonths: true,
    events: events
});

$("#cal_month_3").html("<h4 style='margin-left: 20px;'>" + moment().add(3, 'months').format("MMMM") + "</h4>");
$('#clndr_3').clndr({
    template: $('#calendar-template').html(),
    startWithMonth: moment().add(2, 'months'),
    showAdjacentMonths: true,
    events: events
});
}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

EDIT 14:45
To clarify, here is an example of the events array passed to CLNDR.js

```
[
{
    "date": "2015-07-01",
    "id": "57",
    "type": "consultation"
}, {
    "date": "2015-07-02",
    "id": "58",
    "type": "consultation"
}, {
    "date": "2015-07-03",
    "id": "105",
    "type": "full"
}, {
    "date": "2015-09-30",
    "id": "134",
    "type": "consultation"
}
]
```

Comment: Can you confirm which IE version you're using? (and also confirm that it's not running in compatibility mode or quirks mode)

Comment: I came across the issue in many IE versions, including the newer ones like IE10 and IE11 (tested on multiple platforms and through BrowserStack). And indeed while not running compatibility mode.